# how to create record type using dynamic sql in oracle?

Tags: oracle, collections, plsql, record, dynamic-sql

I have a table named a with column x.

```
create table A (x varchar2(4000));

insert into A values ('select p,q,r from o');
commit;
```

Now I want to create a record type dynamically on the basis of above sql i.e.

```
TYPE rc IS RECORD ( p o.p%type,
                    q o.q%type,  
                    r o.r%type);
```

Please let me know how to create above record on runtime.

If its not possible, please suggest any work around.

Thank you.

Comment: Please modify your post to include at least one citation to "forums". See [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/61071/adding-links-to-comments) for more details for how to create links in posts.

Comment: @jeff6times7 it was random forums, I have closed those pages earlier and missed those URLs.

Comment: Can you post a pseudo code to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @XING Please see the updated post. I hope it will help

Comment: What you need is Method 4 dynamic SQL. Adrian Billington wrote an excellent piece on the topic [check it out](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=422)

Comment: @Aamir Can you explain why you need dynamic types?  Dynamic types imply a dynamic interface, which usually doesn't make sense in SQL and PL/SQL.  It can be done but it's usually easier to have dynamic SQL do *all* of the processing and store the results directly in the final tables.

Comment: I'm not following your example. You have table `A` with column `X`. What is `O`? And your `insert into A` has too many values.

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to use a record of this table in your code you don't need to create a type, you can declare a rowtype variable as bellow

```
CREATE TABLE xx_emp (emp_id NUMBER, emp_name VARCHAR2(100));

DECLARE

  l_emp_type  xx_emp%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

  l_emp_type.emp_id   := 10;
  l_emp_type.emp_name := 'JOE';

END;
```

Comment: It is possible that query will also have a join with another table and have extra column in select. In that case, it won't work. That is why I asked for dynamically.

Comment: If it will use a query with joins i would suggest you to use cursor,

Answer (score 0):

As you commented on a previous answer, I will assume that with "dinamically" you want to create it based on a query that may contain joins,

you can use cursor as bellow

```
  DECLARE
  -- here you declare a cursor named c_cursor_name
  CURSOR c_cursor_name IS SELECT a.emp_name  
                               , b.dept_name 
                            FROM xx_emp  a
                               , xx_Dept b
                           WHERE a.dept_id = b.dept_id;

  -- here you can declare your record based on your cursor
  r_recors_type   c_cursor_name%ROWTYPE;

BEGIN

  -- now you can fill your cursor as you want
  r_recors_type.emp_name := 'JOE';
  r_recors_type.dept_name := 'Marketing';


END;
```

Comment: thank you. But it will also not work in my case. Currently I am using DBMS_SQL package to sort this out. I am about to finish it. Once done will post it here, how I  did this.